# TCC is causing my mac to freeze for 5-20 seconds sporadically throughout the day. How can I fix it?

Tags: permission, performance, accessibility

Sporadically throughout the day while I'm working on my 2017 27" iMac running macOS 10.14.6, the entire system will freeze for 5-20 seconds. There doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason to it, but it does happen the most when utilizing apps that make use of Accessibility permissions, such as xGestures or BetterTouchTool. I later confirmed (as documented in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/407774/my-macs-ui-is-randomly-freezing-for-5-10-seconds-throughout-the-day-how-can-i)) that the problem is TCC; the system WindowServer process is doing some kind of check to make sure a process has the permissions it needs, and it's getting locked up while doing so, causing the entire system to freeze until it finishes. During these times the cursor still moves, but I can't click anything on screen.

Does anyone have any idea what's going wrong here, or how I can fix it?

So far I've tried resetting the TCC database using the command `tccutil reset All`, and while that seemed to make my computer a little snappier at first, as soon as I granted all of the apps I use the permissions they require, the freezes came back. I've also reinstalled macOS from the recovery environment and that didn't fix it either.

I have a 2019 MacBook Pro running the same version of Mojave with much of the same software installed, and it does not have this issue, for what that's worth.

I've also read through [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/352454/system-slowness-how-to-disable-or-short-circuit-tccd-in-mojave-slows-app-su) but it's addressing a different TCC-related issue, and using an MDM profile will not help since its purpose is to add apps to the TCC database without requiring user intervention. This question is not about subsecond delays introduced by TCC when launching apps, but a show-stopping bug in TCC where it literally causes the entire mac to become unresponsive for several seconds.

Update 6/17/2021: one of the triggers for this bug appears to be apps that have an invalid or missing signature. I just managed to consistently trigger this bug in an app with an invalid signature where one of its child processes was trying to send Apple events. I then fixed it by resigning the app with my "Developer ID Application" certificate. I don't know at this point whether that specific kind of certificate is necessary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System slowness: How to disable or short-circuit tccd in Mojave? (slows app & subprocess startup)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/352454/system-slowness-how-to-disable-or-short-circuit-tccd-in-mojave-slows-app-su)

Comment: @EzekielElin I did see that. I don't think it does what I want, if I understand it correctly. From what I can tell, it describes using MDM + a configuration profile to automatically set certain apps as already having some TCC permissions granted. But as far as I can tell, that's equivalent to just granting the apps permission manually, and it will add the appropriate entries to the TCC database. I don't see any way to disable TCC altogether.

Comment: It is the same question, it's just the answer which uses MDM.

Comment: It's not really the same question. App startup is not affected. But running apps are frozen

Comment: Right, but it's still the question of "How do I disable TCC"

Comment: Really, the question I'm asking is "how do I stop the freezes". Disabling TCC is just one possible way of doing that... but it does not seem possible in Mojave. I'll ask another question that's more pointed.

Comment: Right now the question here asks how to fix or disable TCC, as does the original one.

Comment: If you hope for answers not requiring MDM it might be better offer a bounty on the original question (I'm open to do that for you) to get renewed attention to the topc.

Comment: Actually the question does ask two things - how to stop the freezes and how to turn off TCC - the latter is a dup. How to stop is a separate question which the OP is derailing themselves by saying it is TCC. So the OP needs to just ask the first question

Comment: I have edited the question to remove the part about disabling TCC, because a) it's pretty apparent that's not possible, and b) it's not really relevant, because really all I care about is fixing the freezes. I've nominated the question for reopening now that I believe it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for coming back. The question still seems to focus on TCC though. Also you did analyze the freezes in a previous Q&A and came to the conclusion that TCC is causing them. So I'm still a bit confused on how this question here differs from either the question it currently is linked to *or* your previous one. But maybe I'm overthinking things, let's see what the review of the hold leads to.

Comment: My first question was about how to find the source of the freezing, which I figured out and so marked that question as solved. And the linked question is about how to fix some delays when launching an app due to TCC, which is related, but a different question and different issue. So I think this question is adequately different from both. Hopefully others will agree. If not I'll keep working on it.

Comment: I’m tempted to close both questions TBH. Neither narrows down to one app and seem too vague. Only after we have 4 or 5 question showing how TCC can cause specific slowdowns would we have a overall “canonical” answer. We’re not a good place for 20 questions “guess what’s wrong “ with a “slow” Mac. (In my opinion)

Comment: @bmike - I disagree with closing all of this. There is a specific issue in that the mac freezes, hold ups input and then plays it back. The fact that there is no known answer is not a reason to close the question. From the first question knowing that one issue might be TCC is useful to others - who then can try to stop TCC.

Comment: I've also identified the source of the issue with at least some significant specificity: TCC is causing WindowServer to lock up. And yes I'm hoping someone has better knowledge of this sort of thing than having to resort to 20 questions. :-) But I came here because I'm not sure where else to go. It's a pretty severe issue that's really making my mac hard to use, and I'm out of ideas about how to fix it. And pretty much all questions about computer problems comes down to someone having the right esoteric knowledge. I'm hoping someone here has it and can help.

Comment: I’m not casting a binding vote either way, so it’s up to the voting community to vote these. If I wasn’t a binding mod, I’d vote to improve both but I understand others having a different take. So far one person has case a vote to reopen, so it will need a couple more people to reopen it and reverse the duplicate action.

Comment: @GuyGizmo If you are after turning TCC off then the question pointed to is the answer

Comment: @mmmmmm After reading that question and the pages it links to, it reveals there is no way to turn of TCC, which is one of the reasons why I edited and kept this question. I need to find some way to fix TCC rather than trying to disable it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've discovered the problem is apps that are missing a signature, or have an invalid signature.

In these cases, whenever they try to access something that requires going through TCC, most of all using AppleScript or Apple events, the entire system will freeze while TCC churns away at... *something*. My best guess is that it's recalculating a signature for the app in question, and if the app's bundle is quite large, as is the case with some of the invalidly signed apps I was working with, it can take quite a long time. I've discovered that it's reproducible across all of my macOS 10.14 systems.

Why the system needs to freeze during this time is beyond me. That strikes me as some very, very bad design. Essentially the entire window server is blocking while waiting for TCC to finish its work. (See [this earlier question of mine](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/407774/my-macs-ui-is-randomly-freezing-for-5-10-seconds-throughout-the-day-how-can-i) for how I discovered this is the case.)

The solution, more of a workaround really, is to resign the offending app. I've found that using a ad-hoc signature (i.e. `codesign -f -s - /path/to/app.app`) seems to work.